# jpa save worked but no data

Tags: hibernate, jpa, save

I saved data for test by use hibernate but when i call it there is no data and i dont know why..

my test code is like this

```
 @Test
void postPerson() throws Exception{
    PersonDto personDto = PersonDto.of("martin", "programming", "판교", LocalDate.now(), 
"programmer", "010-1111-2222");
    mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/person")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(toJsonString(personDto)))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());

    Person result = personRepository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id")).get(0);


    assertAll(
            () -> assertThat(result.getName()).isEqualTo("martin")
    );
}
```

and controller

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void postPerson(@RequestBody PersonDto personDto){
    personService.put(personDto);
}
```

and service

```
@Transactional
public void put(PersonDto personDto) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.set(personDto);
    person.setName(personDto.getName());
    personRepository.save(person);
}
```

save worked so 201 returned but there is no saved data .. i cant understand..

Answer (score 0):

Tests are rolled back by default. That's why it works but you see no data.
You might temporary add

```
@Rollback(false)
```

to your test.

Comment: Thanks for reply but  where should i put the annotation? i added on method like  
    @Test
    @Rollback(false)
    void postPerson() throws Exception{} 
it doesn't work either ...